# VS Code has suddenly stopped displaying Logic App Standard run history

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

What works:

- ability to edit workflows in VS Code designer
- ability to trigger HTTP and Service bus workflows

What doesn't work:

- ability view run history
- ability to debug through workflows that have run, requires run history

Also having random runtime errors occur at different locations within workflow, for instance, it fails at first activity after trigger called 'Initialize_Workflow_Termination_Status' which is simply initializing a new variable:

```
Job error: correlationId='cb64e379-7cd4-4894-8d9b-35561b8f3313', operationName='FlowRunActionJobCallback.OnJobExecute', jobPartition='A7FBFB6F11034F7389741C57EA305E47:2D08585113587920018044905998230CU00', jobId='08585113587920018044905998230CU00-INTERNAL:3A2EBEGINSCOPE:3A2EWORKFLOW:3A5FTERMINATION:3A5FSTATUS:3A5FIS:3A5FSET', message='The unknown exception is encountered. The current flow run job is failed.', exception='System.InvalidOperationException: The referenced action 'Initialize_Workflow_Termination_Status' with sequencer Id 'INITIALIZE:5FWORKFLOW:5FTERMINATION:5FSTATUS' is not completed successfully. SequencerAction status: '<null>'. SequencerType: ''. All available actions are : ''
```

[image]

It was working 3 days ago, but no longer showing run history.

Tooling versions:

- Visual Studio Code: 1.80.1
- Node: 14.21.3
- Azure Functions Core Tools: 4.0.5198
- Azurite Extension: 3.25.0
- Azure Logic Apps (Standard) Extension: 2.15.4

I've tried following to no effect:

- Reinstall all tooling
- Downgrading Visual Studio Code to 1.76
- Downgrading Azure Logic Apps (Standard) Extension to 1.0.46
- Downgrading Azurite to various versions
- Setting Azurite to loose mode
- Running Azurite externally with debug log to capture potential issues to no effect
- Running Azurite on different ports and using full connection string specifying port numbers
- Running Azurite clean, deleting Azurite data files
- Creating a new Logic App Standard solutions with a simple HTTP trigger workflow and Response

Cannot view run history:
[image: Cannot view run history]

Comment: Workaround: bypass Azurite local storage emulator and use an actual Azure deployed storage account. So change AzureWebJobsStorage value in local.settings.json to Azure hosted storage account connection string.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this same issue since yesterday, and I suspected this had something to do with the Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle.Workflows which got updated yesterday to version 1.28.4. I tried lowering the version from host.json to use the previous one, the issue was still present.

After reading your post, I checked my Azurite extension as well, just in case. And it turns out, it too was updated yesterday. So I downgraded to version 3.24.0 and now I am getting the run histories.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, downgrade to 3.24.0 version. That will work fine. Runs that were trigger in the latest version will be saved and showed when downgrading.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).